# Windows 10 touch screen: active pen works, finger does not

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, touchscreen

My touch screen stopped working following a Windows (10) update.

[image: device]

Strangely, the active pen still works.  A quick google search produces dozens of reports of this (finger touch stops working, but pen still works), primarily for Lenovo laptops.  I've tried all the suggestions, including reverting the Windows update, and even reinstalling Windows.

If the active pen works, it can't be the hardware?

[image: device manager]

I was trying to find a raw input stream from the device, in order to see if my fingers produce anything at all.  Is that possible?  I found a `devcon.exe` command line utility, but it's hard to download independently of a massive SDK, and appears to only show the same info that's in the device manager.

How do you view realtime data streams from input devices?  I'd be curious about this for future reference, and seems like it would quickly determine why my laptop screen is ignorant.